# Page Break is not working for MS WORD 2003

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

The following code is working in the case of MS WORD 2007(docx) but not reflecting in the case of MS WORD 2003(doc). help me.

```
Object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Object objBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
            Object objUnit = Word.WdUnits.wdStory;
            oWord.Selection.EndKey(ref objUnit, ref nullobj);
            oWord.Selection.InsertBreak(ref objBreak);
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? If so, please post it.

Comment: No exception. Simply it is giving LINE BREAK instead of PAGE BREAK.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage, not Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak.